Unable to start metrics server on eks fargate
I am trying to implement eks on fargate. I want to deploy metrics server on eks fargate. I am following official documentation from aws on eks.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/metrics-server.html
Deploy the Metrics Server
Deploy the Metrics Server with the following command:
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml

The following is my components.yaml file to deploy metrics server on eks fargate
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
  name: system:aggregated-metrics-reader
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/metrics
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server-auth-reader
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server:system:auth-delegator
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:metrics-server
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=10250
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=15s
        image: registry.k8s.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.7.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /livez
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
        name: metrics-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 10250
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /readyz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
          seccompProfile:
            type: RuntimeDefault
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-dir
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp-dir
---
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: metrics-server
    namespace: kube-system
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100

I found the pod is running
kubectl get pods
NAME                                  READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-97d899f8f-64sxg               1/1     Running   0          12d
coredns-97d899f8f-frdtc               1/1     Running   0          12d
ebs-csi-controller-848b9bdb6d-67nmb   6/6     Running   0          12d
ebs-csi-controller-848b9bdb6d-vf6vt   6/6     Running   0          12d
metrics-server-5996f9457d-wnxzl       1/1     Running   0          2m59s

When I applied the changes without changing any port or anything from the default source I am getting the below error.
E0618 06:38:44.089251       1 scraper.go:149] "Failed to scrape node" err="Get \"https://172.14.2.13:10250/metrics/resource\": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate is valid for 127.0.0.1, not 172.14.2.13" node="fargate-ip-172-14-2-13.ap-south-2.compute.internal"

I also tried to add
- --kubelet-insecure-tls

in container args:
But again i got the error but this time different error
E0618 06:35:15.173345       1 scraper.go:149] "Failed to scrape node" err="request failed, status: \"403 Forbidden\"" node="fargate-ip-172-14-1-131.ap-south-2.compute.internal"

I read the below statement on official docs:
If you are using Fargate, you will need to change this file. In the default configuration, the metrics server uses port 10250. This port is reserved on Fargate. Replace references to port 10250 in components.yaml with another port, such as 10251.

And then I changed the port 10250 to 10251 and applied the changes again
Below is my updated components.yaml file
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-admin: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-edit: "true"
    rbac.authorization.k8s.io/aggregate-to-view: "true"
  name: system:aggregated-metrics-reader
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes/metrics
  verbs:
  - get
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - pods
  - nodes
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server-auth-reader
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: Role
  name: extension-apiserver-authentication-reader
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server:system:auth-delegator
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:auth-delegator
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: system:metrics-server
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: system:metrics-server
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  ports:
  - name: https
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: https
  selector:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: metrics-server
  namespace: kube-system
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: metrics-server
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: metrics-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - args:
        - --cert-dir=/tmp
        - --secure-port=10251
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP,ExternalIP,Hostname
        - --kubelet-use-node-status-port
        - --metric-resolution=15s
        image: registry.k8s.io/metrics-server/metrics-server:v0.7.1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /livez
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          periodSeconds: 10
        name: metrics-server
        ports:
        - containerPort: 10251
          name: https
          protocol: TCP
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /readyz
            port: https
            scheme: HTTPS
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 10
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 200Mi
        securityContext:
          allowPrivilegeEscalation: false
          capabilities:
            drop:
            - ALL
          readOnlyRootFilesystem: true
          runAsNonRoot: true
          runAsUser: 1000
          seccompProfile:
            type: RuntimeDefault
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /tmp
          name: tmp-dir
      nodeSelector:
        kubernetes.io/os: linux
      priorityClassName: system-cluster-critical
      serviceAccountName: metrics-server
      volumes:
      - emptyDir: {}
        name: tmp-dir
---
apiVersion: apiregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: APIService
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: metrics-server
  name: v1beta1.metrics.k8s.io
spec:
  group: metrics.k8s.io
  groupPriorityMinimum: 100
  insecureSkipTLSVerify: true
  service:
    name: metrics-server
    namespace: kube-system
  version: v1beta1
  versionPriority: 100

Then I got below error
E0618 06:29:38.919461       1 scraper.go:149] "Failed to scrape node" err="Get \"https://172.14.2.118:10250/metrics/resource\": dial tcp 172.14.2.118:10250: connect: connection refused" node="fargate-ip-172-14-2-118.ap-south-2.compute.internal"

I want to run my workloads on fargate. And before metrics server I am already running core dns and ebs-csi controller on fargate(basically all pods that runs on kube-system namespace)
I already tried to implement the same from helm as well as eks blueprint addons. But still i am getting same sort of errors everywhere.
helm release configurations are:
resource "helm_release" "metrics_server" {
  name = "metrics-server"

  repository = "https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/metrics-server/"
  chart      = "metrics-server"
  namespace  = "kube-system"
  version    = "3.12.1"

  values = \[file("${path.module}/values/metrics-server.yaml")\]

}


This is the expected behaviour/error as fargate will not allow pod running(metrics server) to communicate to the node and get the metrics. However metrics server will be able to get the metrics of other running pod.
Ref: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/issues/694#issuecomment-815193036
https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/1798
